# SuiteScript 1.0 Get assemblyitem id from work order record

Tags: netsuite, suitescript

I'm currently trying to build a RESTlet script that will run daily to sync new work order data over from NetSuite to another web application (Tulip). I am attempting to find the ID for an assembly item in the work orders so that I can find its equivalent in a data table in Tulip, but receive the response `"An nlobjSearchColumn contains an invalid column, or is not in proper syntax: assemblyitem."`

Looking at the xml for the work order, I do see the ID listed under assemblyitem, but I don't seem to be able to grab that value. I've tried googling as well as searching the suitescript 1.0 api documentation, but I'm afraid I'm stuck.

Here is my current script:

```
 function getWOSoftLock() {


    var dataoutput = nlapiSearchRecord(
        'workorder',
        null,
        new nlobjSearchFilter('status', null, 'is', 'WorkOrd:B'),
        [
            new nlobjSearchColumn('tranid'),
            new nlobjSearchColumn('status'),
            new nlobjSearchColumn('assemblyitem')
        ]
    );

    if(!dataoutput) {
        nlapiLogExecution('AUDIT', 'No released work orders');
        return [];
    }

    return dataoutput.map(function(res){
        return {
            tranid:res.getValue('tranid'),
            status:res.getValue('status')
        };
    });

}
```

Would anybody be able to direct me towards how I can go about pulling the ID for the assembly item?

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the fun things about NetSuite is that occasionally the field IDs for searching differ from the field IDs specified in the Record Schema.  If you load a work order record, you would be able to access a field with the id 'assemblyitem'.  However, when searching, the same field is referenced simply as 'item'.  Note that to see only the assembly item returned, you would also have to include a filter for Main Line = Yes (or `new nlobjSearchFilter('mainline', null, 'is', 'T')`).